# DOM ready twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery on my website and I have a bug on one page.

I submit a form when the DOM is ready like this:

```
jQuery.(document).ready(function() {
     alert("test"); jQuery("#form").submit(); 
});
```

My form is like this:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;" action="test.php"></form>
```

But when I load my page, the alert appeared twice.
So the big problem is the form which submit twice.

Why the dom is loaded twice?
This bug is only on IE (all version)

Thanks

Comment: @Kiva You got a syntax error: two parens `))` instead of one.

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but it should be `jQuery(document)` (without `.`).

Comment: Yes it's an typo error, I haven't javascript error ;)

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? I tried jQuery 1.4.4 with IE9 and I only got the alert once: http://jsfiddle.net/z2ZjN/

Comment: what happens if you remove the "return false;"?

Comment: I use jQuery 1.4, I try with IE 8 and 6, and I haven't this bug just for one page. So I search ideas but I don't think you can reproduce the bug.

Comment: Do you have iframes in your page?

Comment: @Gerben, nothing change if I remove return false; @Jaime, No Iframe but 2 frames (I know, it's horrible, but I don't choose)

Comment: See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7247

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     alert("test"); 
     $("#form").submit(); 
});
```